# lodash for Objective-C, to filter json object or dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary, lodash

I'm looking for library for Objective-C to extract value from dictionary by filter.

Is there any library like lodash(it is a JS library) for Objective-C in order to filter JSON object or dictionary?

**Sample code:**

```
for (AssetData* data in assestDataArray)
    {
        for (AssetSection * assetSection in data.sections)
        {
            for (AssetField * assetSectionField in assetSection.fields)
            {

            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: "in order to filter json object or dictionary?" For those who are not familiar with lodash, do you have an example in sample code on what you want to do the filter?

Comment: `for (AssetData* data in assestDataArray)
    {
        for (AssetSection * assetSection in data.sections)
        {
            for (AssetField * assetSectionField in assetSection.fields)
            {

}}}` I don't want to loop through this.

Answer (score 0):

try [JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel) - Magical Data Modeling Framework for JSON

JSONModel allows rapid creation of smart data models. You can use it in your iOS, macOS, watchOS and tvOS apps. Automatic introspection of your model classes and JSON input drastically reduces the amount of code you have to write.